# How to get a character from its UTF-16 code points in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-16

I have a list of UTF-16 code points that I need to convert to the actual characters they represent programmatically. This seems unbelievably hard to do in Python 3.

For example, I have the numbers 55357 and 56501 for one character, which I know is this banknote emoji:  But I have no idea how to convert that in Python. I first tried `chr(55357) + chr(56501)`, but Python seems to assume that it is UTF-8 encoded and thus gives me broken Unicode.

I then tried re-encoding the string, but since it's broken UTF-8, it gives me what seems to be broken UTF-16. If I tell it to leave it alone with `(chr(55357) + chr(56501)).encode('utf-8', 'surrogatepass')`, I can actually get a valid bytes of the character, but it's encoded in...CESU-8, for reasons I cannot yet grasp. This is not an encoding Python supports natively, and I can't find a codec to convert it.

I think I could probably write these to the disk and then read them with the right encoding, but that sounds really terrible.

Is there a reasonable way to do this in Python 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is not to mess with `chr` but rather to convert to a byte array, which you can then decode into a string:

```
a, b = 55357, 56501
x = a.to_bytes(2, 'little') + b.to_bytes(2, 'little')

print(x.decode('UTF-16'))
```

This can be generalized for any number of integers:

```
data = [55357, 56501]
b = bytes([x for c in data for x in c.to_bytes(2, 'little')])
result = b.decode('utf-16')
```

The reason something like `chr(55357) + chr(56501)` doesn't work is that `chr` assumes no encoding. It works on the raw Unicode code points, so you are combining two distinct characters. As the other answer points out, you then have to encode this two character string and re-decode it, or just get the bytes and decode once as I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

The folowing code works:

```
cp1 = 55357
cp2 = 56501
(chr(cp1) + chr(cp2)).encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16')
#
```